# Division with remainders displayed on side

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a nice looking division process where the remainders are displayed on the side at each step. I want to produce exactly this (but, of course, be able to extend it to longer divisions if need):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Have you tried using the `xlop` package?  How far did you get?  This seems to be noted as a possible feature for future versions there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\rlwd{.5pt} \def\rlht{2.2ex} \def\rldp{.5ex}
\def\mydiv#1{~%
  \rule[-\rldp]{\rlwd}{\rlht}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{~#1}%
  \stackunder[\dimexpr\rldp-\rlwd]{~#1}{\rule{\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
4\mydiv{198} &\\
4\mydiv{49}  & remainder 2\\
4\mydiv{12}  & remainder 1\\
4\mydiv{3}   & remainder 0\\
0            & remainder 3
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This also frees you from the burden of actually doing the computations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showbase}{O{c}mm}
 {% #1 is the alignment for tabular
  % #2 is the number to be manipulated
  % #3 is the base
  \induktio_showbase:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__induktio_table_contents_tl
\int_new:N \l__induktio_quotient_int
\int_new:N \l__induktio_remainder_int
\bool_new:N \l__induktio_first_row_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__induktio_add_row:nn #1 #2
 {% #1 is the base, #2 is the quotient
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__induktio_table_contents_tl
   {
    \int_compare:nF { #2 == 0 } { #1~ }
    \__induktio_quotient:n { #2 }
    &
    \bool_if:NF \l__induktio_first_row_bool
     {
      remainder~\int_to_arabic:n { \l__induktio_remainder_int }
     }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \induktio_showbase:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__induktio_table_contents_tl
  \bool_set_true:N \l__induktio_first_row_bool
  \int_set:Nn \l__induktio_quotient_int { #2 }
  \__induktio_recursion:n { #3 }
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}rl@{}}
  \tl_use:N \l__induktio_table_contents_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__induktio_recursion:n #1
 {% #1 is the base
  \__induktio_add_row:nn { #1 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__induktio_quotient_int } }
  \bool_set_false:N \l__induktio_first_row_bool
  \int_set:Nn \l__induktio_remainder_int
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \l__induktio_quotient_int } { #1 }
   }
  \int_set:Nn \l__induktio_quotient_int
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__induktio_quotient_int } { #1 }
   }
  \int_compare:nTF { \l__induktio_quotient_int == 0 }
   {
    \__induktio_add_row:nn { #1 } { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__induktio_quotient_int } }
   }
   {
    \__induktio_recursion:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__induktio_quotient:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 0 }
   {
    #1
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}\vline\ #1\\\hline\end{tabular}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\semibox}

\begin{document}
\showbase[t]{198}{4}\qquad
\showbase[t]{198}{2}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\showbase` can be `c` (default), `t` or `b` (it is passed to the underlying `tabular`).

A recursion is started, which adds row by row to a token list variable; it ends when the quotient is zero.

[image]