# How to type short division?

Tags: tables, tabularx, arithmetic

I am typing elementary arithmetics, is there any one knows how to type this ?

[image]

I know perhaps there's a package "polynom" could solve this problem,
but is there any method that could work without calling external packages?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there a particular reason why would you try to avoid packages?

Comment: Related?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210648/division-with-remainders-displayed-on-side

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/repeated-division-converting-from-base-10-to-another-base/114005#114005

Comment: @Ruben, because I am not going to use the LaTeX code on my local computer, I want to upload them to server some where else

Answer (score 5):

Not going into deep explanations, but this uses only Plain TeX macros. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\shortdiv}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\big|$}%
    \def\short@div@strut{\vrule width0pt height\ht\z@ depth\dp\z@}%
    \dimen@=-.5em
    \short@div#1;\short@div;
  }%
}

\def\short@div#1;{%
  \ifx\short@div#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\short@@div#1,\@nil}%
}

\def\short@@div#1,#2\@nil{%
  \advance\dimen@ .5em
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    % last step
    \hbox{\kern\dimen@$\short@div@strut#1$}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \short@@@div#1,#2%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  \short@div
}
\def\short@@@div#1,#2,{%
  \hbox{\kern\dimen@$\short@div@strut#1\,$\short@@@@div{#2}}%
}
\def\short@@@@div#1{%
  \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\,\short@div@strut#1$}%
  \dimen@=1em \ifdim\wd\z@>1em \dimen@=\wd\z@ \advance\dimen@ .5em \fi
  \vrule\kern-0.4pt\vtop{\hbox to \dimen@{$\,\short@div@strut#1$\hss}\hrule}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\shortdiv{2,a;2,b;2,c;3,d;3,e;5,33333;5,g;7}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adapting my answer at [Division with remainders displayed on side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210648/division-with-remainders-displayed-on-side).  EDITED to adapt its use to arguments with descenders AND to extend the horizontal rule length AND use math mode for the arguments AND to take box measurements in math mode AND extended the strutheight to the above line.

EDITED again to automate the indents.  The indent is reset to 0pt following each invocation of `\remainder{}` or alternately by passing an optional `[0]` to the first invocation of `\mydiv` (the optional argument is the indent level).

EDITED to remove version that uses packages.

Here, I took the `\stackengine` macro, and condensed it down by hardwiring all the parameters to fit the current problem.  Thus, I call it `\dumbstackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{divline}
\def\rlwd{.5pt} \def\rlht{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox} \def\rldp{.75ex}
\newcommand\mydiv[3][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\stepcounter{divline}\else\setcounter{divline}{#1}\fi%
  \mbox{}\hspace{\thedivline\dimexpr1ex}#2~\setbox0=\hbox{~$#3$}%
  \dumbstackengine{-\rlwd}{\rule[-\rldp]{\rlwd}{\rlht}~#3}{\rule{\dimexpr4pt+\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\def\remainder#1{\stepcounter{divline}%
  \mbox{}\hspace{\dimexpr1ex+\thedivline\dimexpr1ex}~#1\setcounter{divline}{0}}
\makeatletter
\global\newlength\@stackedboxwidth
\newlength\@boxshift
\newsavebox\@addedbox
\newsavebox\@anchorbox
\newcommand*\dumbstackengine[3]{%
    \sbox{\@anchorbox}{$#2$}%
    \sbox{\@addedbox}{$#3$}%
    \setlength{\@stackedboxwidth}{\wd\@anchorbox}%
      \ifdim\wd\@addedbox>\@stackedboxwidth%
        \setlength{\@stackedboxwidth}{\wd\@addedbox}%
      \fi%
        \setlength{\@boxshift}{\dimexpr-\dp\@anchorbox -\ht\@addedbox -#1}%
        \usebox{\@anchorbox}%
        \hspace{-\wd\@anchorbox}%
        \raisebox{\@boxshift}{\usebox{\@addedbox}}%
        \hspace{-\wd\@addedbox}%
        \hspace{\@stackedboxwidth}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\mydiv{2}{a} \\
\mydiv{2}{b} \\
\mydiv{2}{c} \\
\mydiv{3}{d} \\
\mydiv{3}{e} \\
\mydiv{5}{34689} \\
\mydiv{5}{g} \\
\remainder{7}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact spacing needs some variation of the following might work.

```
\parindent=0pt
\newbox\leftbox
\newbox\rightbox
\newbox\skipbox
\def\div#1#2{\hskip\wd\skipbox\setbox\skipbox\hbox{\unhcopy\skipbox#1}
\setbox\leftbox\hbox{#1}\unhcopy\leftbox\vrule height 2ex depth 1pt width .5pt
\setbox\rightbox\hbox{#2}\vrule height-.5pt depth1pt width\wd\rightbox\hskip-\wd\rightbox\unhcopy\rightbox\par}
\div{2}{a}
\div{3}{b}
\div{123}{abcd}
\bye
```

Comment: This throws an error:  `! Undefined control sequence.
\div ...th\wd \rightbox \hskip -\wd \rightbox \un 
                                                  \^^Mhcopy\rightbox \par 
l.9 \div{2}{a}
              
? `  And the output is strange: `2Lhcopyj` `3Lhcopyj` `123Lhcopyj`

Comment: AboAmmar: fixed now