# Prime factorization

Tags: tables, mathjax

Is there any way that I can create the following in LaTeX which renders using MathJax:

[image]

Comment: MathJax doesn't support all LaTeX commands, in particular `\cline` (which it should). It's very easy to make that table for LaTeX, but it's difficult (probably impossible) to have code that can be used in either contexts. Werner's trick is nice for MathJax, but it would be awful in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254633/how-to-type-short-division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the following:

```
$$
  \begin{array}{|l}
    \llap{2~~~~} 12600 \\ \hline
    \llap{2~~~~} 6300  \\ \hline
    \llap{2~~~~} 3150  \\ \hline
    \llap{5~~~~} 1575  \\ \hline
    \llap{5~~~~} 315   \\ \hline
    \llap{7~~~~} 63    \\ \hline
    \llap{3~~~~} 9     \\ \hline
                 3
  \end{array}
$$
```

Here's output as rendered on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... `$$  $$`?

Comment: @Bernard That's mathjax math environment

Comment: @Bernard I am curious if you could explain exactly what would be wrong with `$$ .. $$` in LaTeX code. The LaTeX `\[ ..\]`is basically broken if you don't load `amsmath`.

Comment: @jfbu: I always use  `amsmath` — actually I always load `mathtools` (and everyone should, I think). The main reason is `fleqn` is broken.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't know about `fleqn` or forgot as I use it rarely. I do use `mathtools` almost always (at least for specifying intervals à la French `]a,b[` etc...) but didn't know it fixed `fleqn`. On the other hand, careful with `\mathtoolset{centercolon}` as it breaks frenchb, or the opposite, due to Babel not worrying about math active characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here I create `\mydiv` to actually do the calculations, if you supply the successive prime factors.   The syntax is `\mydiv[<dividend>]{<divisor>}`.  If `<dividend>` is omitted, the prior calculated dividend is used.

The macro detects when the factorization is complete.

If you actually enter a non-factor, an error is provided.

In case Mathjax doesn't allow access to `stackengine`, I have provided streamlined code to sit in its place...

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\rlwd{.5pt} \def\rlht{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox} \def\rldp{.75ex}
\newcommand\mydiv[2][\relax]{\noindent%
  \if\relax#1\relax%
    \xdef\theremainder{\the\numexpr\dividend - %
      \numexpr\numexpr\dividend/\divisor\relax*\divisor\relax\relax}%
    \xdef\dividend{\the\numexpr\dividend/\divisor\relax}%
  \else%
    \xdef\dividend{#1}%
    \xdef\theremainder{0}%
  \fi%
  \xdef\divisor{#2}%
  \ifnum\dividend=\divisor\finishmydiv\checkfactor\else%
  \makebox[3ex][r]{#2}~\setbox0=\hbox{~$\dividend$}%
  \dumbstackengine{-\rlwd}{\rule[-\rldp]{\rlwd}{\rlht}~\dividend}{\rule{\dimexpr4pt+\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
\checkfactor%
\\%
  \fi%
}
\def\finishmydiv{%
  \makebox[3ex][r]{}\hspace{\dimexpr1ex%
  }~\dividend\relax}
\def\checkfactor{\ifnum\theremainder=0\relax\else\ [Remainder${}=\theremainder$]\fi}
%%% \EITHER THIS (IF stackengine IS NOT AVAILABLE+)
%\makeatletter
%\global\newlength\@stackedboxwidth
%\newlength\@boxshift
%\newsavebox\@addedbox
%\newsavebox\@anchorbox
%\newcommand*\dumbstackengine[3]{%
%    \sbox{\@anchorbox}{$#2$}%
%    \sbox{\@addedbox}{$#3$}%
%    \setlength{\@stackedboxwidth}{\wd\@anchorbox}%
%      \ifdim\wd\@addedbox>\@stackedboxwidth%
%        \setlength{\@stackedboxwidth}{\wd\@addedbox}%
%      \fi%
%        \setlength{\@boxshift}{\dimexpr-\dp\@anchorbox -\ht\@addedbox -#1}%
%        \usebox{\@anchorbox}%
%        \hspace{-\wd\@anchorbox}%
%        \raisebox{\@boxshift}{\usebox{\@addedbox}}%
%        \hspace{-\wd\@addedbox}%
%        \hspace{\@stackedboxwidth}%
%}
%\makeatother
%%% OR
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand*\dumbstackengine[3]{\stackengine{#1}{#2}{#3}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}}
%%%
\begin{document}
\mydiv[12600]{2} 
\mydiv{2} 
\mydiv{2} 
\mydiv{5} 
\mydiv{5} 
\mydiv{7} 
\mydiv{3} 
\mydiv{3}\medskip

\mydiv[60]{3} 
\mydiv{3} 
\mydiv{5}
\mydiv{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Loosely based on my answer at [How to type short division?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254633/how-to-type-short-division)