# How to write Factorisation

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write the prime factorisation of 60 in latex. Using underline and vertical bar, I was able to create something similar to what I intended. Is there a better way to do so?

```
$5| \underline{60}$        
$3| \underline{12}$              
$2| \underline{4}$                                              
$\color{white}{--}2$
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334929/134144

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. I'm glad it worked :)