# Setting out division questions

Tags: math-mode

I would like to produce a something like this;

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
&&3&1&0&r&1\\\hline
3&)&9&3&1&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but with random numbers and looking a little nicer if possible

Comment: Please revise the codes to make it looks normal.

Comment: Maybe look for intlongdivision package

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476518/displaying-the-complete-long-division

Answer (score 1):

Use the `longdivision` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longdivision}
\begin{document}
    \longdivision[stage=0]{931}{3}\quad
    \longdivision[stage=1]{931}{3}\quad
    \longdivision[stage=2]{931}{3}\quad
    \longdivision[stage=3]{931}{3}\quad
    \longdivision[stage=4]{931}{3}\quad
    \longdivision{931}{3}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the imput but i wanted the simple division without the long division at the bottom and just to give a remainder. But I like your stepwise way for long divison, I might use it.

Comment: @PaulA See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210665/140814

Comment: Thanks for all your help but I think I need to post the question again with more clarification.